# Button is glued to the bottom of div

Tags: html, css, button, margin

This is my current code:

```css
#nav {
    height:10vw;
    width:90vw;
    top:0;
    background-color:#d6d6d6;
    padding:20px;
    border:4px solid black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#toFileCreator {
    margin-right:90vw;
    z-index:999;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h1>
        <center>Web-TXT</center>
    </h1>
    <br>
    <button onclick="Go_to_file_creator()" id="toFileCreator">
        <h1></h1>File creator</h1>
    </button>
</div>
```

I tried to use margin and padding for the button to be aligned properly but it doesn't work. It is waayy below where it should be in the code snippet, but it is a bit better in my code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @MisterJojo VScode just keeps adding auto closing tags and i dont notice sometimes, ill fix it

Comment: Where do you want to put it?

Comment: @XMehdi01 center/left of nav div

Comment: Do you want it included <div> ?

Answer (score 0):

You must work the `<button>` within a single `<div>` and apply a specific style

This is update code:

```css
#nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

#btnStyle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#toFileCreator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h1>
        <center>Web-TXT</center>
    </h1>
    <br>
  </div>
<div id="btnStyle">
    <button onclick="Go_to_file_creator()" id="toFileCreator">
        <h1>File creator</h1>
    </button>
</div>
```